# How to plot a broken line in R?

Tags: r, plot

So I have the following MWE, a horizontal line expresses the mean of a particular day and the points are measurements of emotion.

I'd like to draw a line instead of points within a day between the points, but the line must have breaks between days. I can't seem to figure out how to do this.
I tried the example on [this page](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Plotting-a-broken-line-td820123.html), but that does not seem to work for my data.
A friend of mine managed to do this for the horizontal lines (they have spaces between days), but I can't seem to change my code to let it work for my measurements within days.

MWE:

```
beeps.MWE <- c(91.188697, 87.846194, 93.166418, 96.249094, 95.495146, 99.362597, 94.373646, 
81.995712, 87.626009, 91.880172, 93.112647, 99.349234, 87.073372, 85.161982, 88.119728, 
89.738318, 68.891181, 62.504569, 75.131526, 56.035989, 66.035109, 56.012537)

day.MWE <- rep(c(91.35869, 63.17620), each = 11)

loc.MWE <- c(8, 15)

plot(day.MWE, type = "n", pch = 15, cex = 1.5, ylim = c(40, 110), bty = "n", 
ylab = "score on PA/NA", xlab = "days of person i", axes = FALSE)
dayUn <- unique(day.MWE)
for (i in seq_along(dayUn))
{
  points(which(day.MWE==dayUn[i]),day.MWE[day.MWE==dayUn[i]], type = 'l', lwd = "2")
}
points(1:length(beeps.MWE), beeps.MWE, type = "p")
lines(1:length(beeps.MWE), rep(mean(day.MWE), 22), lwd = "2", lty = 2)
axis(1, at = c(1, 20), labels = c("day 1", "day 2"))
axis(2, las = 1)
```

This is the output of the above code:

[image]

Comment: Try adding this to your loop: `points(which(day.MWE==dayUn[i]),beeps.MWE[day.MWE==dayUn[i]], type = 'l', lwd = "2", col=i)`.

Comment: Yep that almost works! I only need to keep the horizontal lines that were already there, and they disappear now

Comment: That's strange. I meant _adding_ that line to the loop, so the loop contains two calls to `points`: (1) the one already in your code that produces the horizontal lines and (2) the one in my earlier comment that produces the line between points.

Comment: whoops must have read your comment wrong, but it works! thanks

Comment: @koekenbakker can you add this as an answer so Jolanda can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there with the code provided. Just add a line to the loop to draw the lines between the points:

```
for (i in seq_along(dayUn)){

  # draw horizontal lines to show the mean per day
  points(which(day.MWE==dayUn[i]),day.MWE[day.MWE==dayUn[i]], type = 'l', lwd = "2")

  # draw a line that connects points within a day
  points(which(day.MWE==dayUn[i]),beeps.MWE[day.MWE==dayUn[i]], lwd = "2", type='l')
}
```

Also note that `points(x,y,type='l')` is the same as `lines(x,y)`. Makes more sense ;)
[image]