# adding mean score to plot in R

Tags: r, plot

This question is related to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283335/how-to-plot-a-broken-line-in-r) I asked earlier.

So I've got some code with which I  someone's overall mean emotion (dashed line), mean emotion per day (horizontal grey lines) and emotions measured per occasion (red line). I need to add a line that connect means per day. So in this case it means that I have to plot a line between the two grey lines. I have added a picture below in which the green line represents what kind of line I want to add.

[image]

MWE:

```
beeps.MWE <- c(91.188697, 87.846194, 93.166418, 96.249094, 95.495146, 99.362597, 94.373646, 
81.995712, 87.626009, 91.880172, 93.112647, 99.349234, 87.073372, 85.161982, 88.119728, 
89.738318, 68.891181, 62.504569, 75.131526, 56.035989, 66.035109, 56.012537)

day.MWE <- rep(c(91.35869, 63.17620), each = 11)

loc.MWE <- c(8, 15)

plot(day.MWE, type = "n", pch = 15, cex = 1.5, ylim = c(40, 110), bty = "n", 
ylab = "score on PA/NA", xlab = "days of person i", axes = FALSE)
dayUn <- unique(day.MWE)
for (i in seq_along(dayUn))
{
  lines(which(day.MWE==dayUn[i]),day.MWE[day.MWE==dayUn[i]], lwd = "2", col = "grey")
  lines(which(day.MWE==dayUn[i]),day.MWE[day.MWE==dayUn[i]], lwd = "2")
}
lines(1:length(beeps.MWE), rep(mean(day.MWE), 22), lwd = "2", lty = 2)
axis(1, at = c(1, 20), labels = c("day 1", "day 2"))
axis(2, las = 1)
```

This is the output of the above code:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an unknown (or large) number of days you can do it in several ways, but an easy way is to add

```
if(i>1){
    lines(c(mean(which(day.MWE==dayUn[i-1])),mean(which(day.MWE==dayUn[i]))),dayUn[(i-1):i],col="green",lwd=5)
}
```

inside the for-loop. This will draw a line from day *i-1* to day *i* for day *i=2,3,...*.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the same way you add any other `lines` to a plot - with `lines`:

```
lines(c(mean(which(day.MWE==dayUn[1])),mean(which(day.MWE==dayUn[2]))),dayUn,col="green",lwd=5)
```

Comment: thanks! One question: how would you accomplish this when you have, say, 3 days instead of two?